# How to limit the internet bandwidth to specific department in my company, using a Cisco Router?

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, bandwidth

I have this case:

In my Company we have 2 Internet Access in production R1-A router and R2-B router they are both in separate networks, R2-B have the highest priority which it use to Call Center.

were i Want to focus on R1-A that router is a Cisco Router 829F is currently performing NAT Overload to a Huawei HG8245H (Modem ISP) then the hole company connects to a 24-Port Gigabit Rackmount Switch TL-SG1024 (Non Administrable Switch).

All network infracture in the internal network IP adress is 192.168.1.0/24

My internet bandwidth is 10/10 mpbs

Topology:

```
Modem--> Router Cisco 829F--> Switch
```

How do i preform a bandwidth control to specific department or specific host?

What topic or subject i should research? (VLAN,Inter-Vlan Routing)?

What is the best approach or solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Class-Based Policing](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/quality-of-service-qos/qos-policing/10118-cbpcar.html).  Since you cannot administer the switch, you will likely have to match traffic based on IP access list with can be processor intensive.  In any case search cisco.com for class-based policing for additional configuration examples.

```
    Router(config)# class-map access-match
     Router(config-cmap)# match access-group 1
     Router(config-cmap)# exit
     Router(config)# policy-map police-setting
     Router(config-pmap)# class access-match
     Router(config-pmap-c)# police 8000 1000 conform-action transmit exceed-action drop
     Router(config-pmap-c)# exit
     Router(config-pmap)# exit
     Router(config)# interface fastethernet 0/0
     Router(config-if)# service-policy output police-setting
```

Comment: Policing will give poor performance and wastes bandwidth.   Better to use queuing and shaping, so they can use unused bandwidth.

Comment: @Ron. Hi, could you please post some links towards shaping/queuing? That is quite a good option to consider.

Comment: I forgot to tell how do i limit a specific host?

Comment: probably the best way is to ensure that hosts MAC address is always given a particular IP address via the DHCP server.  Then use an access control list as the classifying means.